# Promise {<pending>} on watching a Vuex action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to watch a Vuex action on Vue Router query change and it's not working. When I do a `console.log` on the method inside the watch, it's giving me `Promise {<pending>}`. However, it works fine when called in `created()`:

```
watch: {
    '$route.query.cat'() {
        this.getPhotos().then(() => this.setTotalPages())
        console.log(this.getPhotos()) <---gives me Promise {<pending>}
    }
},

methods: {
    getPhotos() {
        return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.photoRequest)
    })
},
```

The log:

```
Promise {<pending>}
   __proto__: Promise
   [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
   [[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

`getItems` Vuex action:

```
getItems({ getters, commit }, { type, params, showLoading = false }) {
    if ( ! getters.request({ type, params }) ) {
      if (showLoading) {
        commit('SET_LOADING', true)
      }
      return fetchItems({ type, params })
        .then(({ data: items, headers: { 'x-wp-total': total, 'x-wp-totalpages': totalPages } }) => {
          items.forEach(item => commit('ADD_ITEM', { type, item }))
          commit('ADD_REQUEST', { type, request: { params, total: parseInt(total), totalPages: parseInt(totalPages), data: items.map(i => i.id) } })
          if (showLoading) {
            commit('SET_LOADING', false)
          }
        })
    }
},
```

EDIT:

I need to be able to update a property in my data request on query change. This is my data:

```
photoRequest: {
  type: 'photos',
  params: { 
    per_page: 30,
    page: this.page,
    photos_cat: this.$route.query.cat
 }, 
 showLoading: true 
},
```

So basically get the new route query value in the `photos_cat` property and update `this.getPhotos()` which returns an array

Comment: Because when you log it, it is in **pending** state. What's your desirable output?

Answer (score 0):

```
watch: {
  '$route.query.cat'(val) {
        // update data value to new val
        this.photoRequest.params.photos_cat = val
        // then you call your api call and handle response
        this.getPhotos().then(data => this.setTotalPages())
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only once after page load. Doing console.log(data) inside .then() is giving me undefined